# WPF | Multibinding not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Im trying to use multibinding as i have two textboxes to validate for `Text.Length`.

Here is my code.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="107,238,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button x:Name="btnAddBenefeciary" Content="Add Beneficiary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" RenderTransformOrigin="0.587,0.65" Height="28" Click="btnAddBenefeciary_Click">
        <Button.IsEnabled>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsEnabledConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="tbFatherName" Path="Text.Length"/>
                <Binding ElementName="tbFatherName" Path="Text.Length" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.IsEnabled>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In the Same File i added this line under `<Window.Resources>`

```
<local:IsEnabledConverter x:Key="IsEnabledConverter" />
```

But i am not sure where to put this piece of code so i did put in its own xaml.cs file of which this window belongs.

```
public class IsEnabledConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (var isValid in values)
            if (isValid as bool? == false)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Did i needed to create another file or is it fine to use this piece of code in this same file as no one said anything in description of creating new file..

I tried to follow these guide lines.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b9cd042-cacb-4aaa-9e17-2d615c44ee22/can-i-bind-a-controls-isenabled-to-the-selectedindex-of-one-or-more-comboboxes?forum=wpf

http://developingfor.net/2009/01/21/multibinding-in-wpf/

[Making a Button IsEnabled state depend on two textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066097/making-a-button-isenabled-state-depend-on-two-textboxes)

So if i have to create new file, how will i reference this to the new file.. Sorry again as i am new to WPF and .NET.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Did changes as per described in answer but getting new errors..

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

**Update 2:**

Tried like this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The converter class can be in any folder/file you want, the namespace of the converter is important.
But it's a good habit to put converters - and any classes for that mather - in seperate files called the same as the class their contain. And putting converter classes in a seperate "Converters" folder.
As how to reference it, you need to declare the namespace of the converter in your xaml file where you want to use it:

```
<Window 
....
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:YourProject.ConvertersNamespace"
....
>
```

Then you can reference the converter class in the resources:

```
<converters:IsEnabledConverter x:Key="IsEnabledConverter" />
```

And then use the converter in you multi binding as you described. Altough you have in your multibinding two identical bindings to the tbFatherName element name, but I guess that's just a typo.

Comment: Thankyou for reply sir,
Added like this
`xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:RMS.IsEnabledConverter"`
But i am getting error of could not found..

I did created a folder named 'Converters and create a new Class file named IsEnabledConverter'

Comment: If you created such folder, most probarly the namespace would be 'xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:RMS.Converters.IsEnabledConverter"' please look at the namespace where the IsEnabledConverter class resides

Comment: i moved it outside of folder, thought as it might be fixed. but still the same issue..

i have updated the question with screen shot.

Comment: Didn't noticed that you have added the *class name* to the namespace definition, it should be: "'xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:RMS.Converters" - you really nead firstly learn "C#" because after this issue you will get a lot o new ones without the basics of C#

Comment: xD. Thats the idea.. But for the this project sake i really need help. As My Boss wants to Finish it ASAP.

Added The ScreenShot for another Update.

Another Line Started Giving Error.

Comment: As you can see in the second error, you have the IsEnabledConverter declared twice, I would bet you didn't removed it from codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Content="Confirm" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,160,0,0"

Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="80">

```
        <Button.CommandParameter>

            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomMultiValueConverterKey}">

                <Binding ElementName="cboCountry" Path="SelectedValue"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="cboShopKeeperID" Path="SelectedValue"/>

            </MultiBinding>

        </Button.CommandParameter>

    </Button>
```

and the back have to write

CommonControlHandlers.populateControls("CALL GetCountryList()", cboCountry);

```
     CommonControlHandlers.populateControls<ComboBox>("CALL GetShopKeeperList()", cboShopKeeperID);
```